# Jquery .html() adds only one row to the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, rows

I am using `append()` to add new rows to the table, but the problem is that I need to remove the old rows before adding new.

```
success: function(response) {
    response.AnArray.forEach( function (arrayItem){
        $('.tableName > tbody').append('<tr>...</tr>');
    });
}
```

Then I switched to `html()` over `append()`, now that adds only one row to the table.

**Note :**

> $('.tableName > tbody').empty();

Is not working in my case.

What am I missing?

Comment: _Then i switched to `html()`_: Do you mean you replaced `append` with `html`?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah, That's what i mean, Edited.

Comment: can you show the current code too? What does the code look like at the moment?

Comment: That is exactly the reason. Why not just change the content of the row?

Comment: I know the problem, when you use the html() function inside the loop you replace the content every time the loop increase, try to create all the html code in a var inside the loop then use the html() to insert the content

Comment: Try $('.createPOVTable > tbody').html(''); to empty the existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is similar to @Shree, But use `html()` there instead of append.

```
success: function(response) {
    $('.createPOVTable > tbody').empty();
    var htmlData = '';
    response.AnArray.forEach( function (arrayItem){
      htmlData += '<tr>...</tr>';
    });
    $('.createPOVTable > tbody').html(htmlData)
}
```

Comment: Plus one for that.

Answer (score 4):

.html() completely replaces the contents of the tbody on each iteration, so it will always just show the last row inserted.
Instead, empty out the tbody before you start the iteration, then use append to add the new row, as below:

```js
success: function(response) {
    $('.createPOVTable > tbody').empty();
    response.AnArray.forEach( function (arrayItem){
        $('.createPOVTable > tbody').append('<tr>...</tr>');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to remove all the previous rows, what you can do is

```
$("#tbodyID").empty();
```

This will clear the table body and then use

```
$("#tbodyID").append('<tr>...</tr>');
```

So, your final code should look like

```
success: function(response) {
   $("#tbodyID").empty();
response.AnArray.forEach( function (arrayItem){
    $("#tbodyID").append('<tr>...</tr>');
});
}
```

Comment: what is the `Id` of your `tbody` ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use  append in every loop so first generate mark up as a string and append ones out side the loop like this.

```
success: function(response) {
    $('.createPOVTable > tbody').empty();
    var html = '';
    response.AnArray.forEach( function (arrayItem){
      html += '<tr>...</tr>';
    });
    $('.createPOVTable > tbody').append(html)
}
```

Comment: Performance problem. Every time dome manipulation is slower .So create string and append once.

Comment: Yup, Nice one there .

Comment: I had to still use html not append, Please see @Gammer answer.
Thanks BTW.